# CarrierWave resize_to_limit Controller error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, resize, carrierwave

Whenever I place the code

```
process resize_to_limit: [400, 400]
```

(My application works just fine without the above code.)

I get the error:

> Errno::ENOENT in MicropostsController#create

No such file or directory - identify

Which points to the line

```
@micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
```

in my microposts_controller file

I do not know what's causing and I've been over it for over an hour already. Can somebody explain to me why this is happening?

Here are my codes:

**picture_uploader.rb**

```
class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  process resize_to_limit: [400, 400]

  storage :file


  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end


  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

end
```

**microposts_controller.rb**

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy

def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save
        flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
        redirect_to root_url
    else
        @feed_items = []
        render 'static_pages/home'
    end
end

def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Micropost deleted"
    redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
end



private

    def micropost_params
        params.require(:micropost).permit(:content, :picture)
    end


    def correct_user
        @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
        redirect_to root_url if @micropost.nil?
    end

 end
```

**UPDATE**

I have fixed the error and the one that caused it is that I don't have ImageMagick installed from Homebrew. :)

Comment: Does this happen in your local dev environment or on a remote server? The problem seems to be that the file (either temp file or converted file) can't be saved in the folder defined in `def store_dir`. It probably doesn't exist yet, but Carrierwave should create it as far as I remember. My suggestions:  

- check if the folder has any strange permissions which might prevent the file from being saved  
- use a simpler path that definitely exists, like `/uploads`, and remember to create the uploads folder

Comment: I'm on my local dev environment. I've checked the temp folder and the image I've uploaded has been sent there.

Comment: The final, converted image has been saved in the temp folder? That doesn't seem right. It should end up in the folder you set in *store_dir`. Again, try to simplify the store_dir, use a simple folder that definitely exists and avoid any dynamic string interpolations for now. See if it works and go from there there.

Comment: Okay so I've made a new folder that points from the store_dir method and the upload doesn't get sent there. What seems to be the matter with this? I'm still new to Rails so I'm not really familiar with this.

Comment: I actually haven't installed ImageMagick from Homebrew and it was what caused the problem. Thank you so much for helping me out on this. :)

Answer (score 0):

If it's simply the image magic problem you can write your validation in a conditional. Like the `if Rails.env.production?` which is used in production to send carrier wave images to fog leaving file for development only.

Obviously this means your validation is only operational in the production environment so you won't get the resize in development but if you're testing in both it won't matter as much as having the actual upload work. It's a work around but gives seamless access to manually test in both without having to install anything.